# I want to have one variable see that its value is the name of another and take its array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

```
var t1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;

var t2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;

var VA = ["VA", 4, 10.8, 18];

var DE = [3, 10.9, 6];

var GA = [77, 23.3, 8];

var AA = [21, 11, 2];

var KS = [23, 10.3, 3];

var LE = [2, 11.7, 7];

var NA = [11, 14.3, 5];

var UA = [71, 15.1, 16];
```

I have some of the above code and that my first variable t1 will have a string value of any of my other variables (excluding t2) and I want it to see that and be able to use the other arrays.

t1 or t2 would have a value inputed such as VA or DE

For an example

t2 might be inputed as GA

and for my code I would want it to see that t2 is GA and cahnage t2 to the variable GA above.

Comment: What is the role of `t2` in this question?

Comment: Group your variables in an object or an array!

Comment: Post an example (a value of `t2` and what should be your desired  outcome)!

Comment: An object of arrays would be so much better than a bunch of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create those variables as object properties. Here is how the solution would work then:

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
var out = document.getElementById('out');

var vars = {
    VA: ["VA", 4, 10.8, 18],
    DE: [3, 10.9, 6],
    GA: [77, 23.3, 8],
    AA: [21, 11, 2],
    KS: [23, 10.3, 3],
    LE: [2, 11.7, 7],
    NA: [11, 14.3, 5],
    UA: [71, 15.1, 16]
};

t1.oninput = function() { 
    var name = t1.value;
    var value = vars[name];
    // Use value in any desired way.
    out.textContent = JSON.stringify(value);
}
```

```html
Variable: <input id="t1"> (example: "VA")<br>
Content: <span id="out"></span>
```

Or, with two inputs, and an in-place replacement as you type:

```js
var t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
var t2 = document.getElementById('t2');

var vars = {
    VA: ["VA", 4, 10.8, 18],
    DE: [3, 10.9, 6],
    GA: [77, 23.3, 8],
    AA: [21, 11, 2],
    KS: [23, 10.3, 3],
    LE: [2, 11.7, 7],
    NA: [11, 14.3, 5],
    UA: [71, 15.1, 16]
};

t1.oninput = t2.oninput = function(e) { 
    var name = e.target.value;
    if (name in vars) {
        var value = vars[name];
        // Use value in any desired way. 
        e.target.value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }
}
```

```html
Variable 1: <input id="t1"> (example: "VA")<br>
Variable 2: <input id="t2">
```